# How do I remove these kinds of light bulbs?

Tags: light

These are in my basement bathroom. I tried unscrewing it, but it just spun around. Tried pulling on it but not too hard because I was afraid of breaking it off in the socket.[image]

Comment: Does the glass cover spin around inside the metal base?  Or is the whole metal base spinning on the straight bar beneath it?  Either way does the white threaded part also spin?

Comment: Does the clear cover move at all when you *push* on it (axially)?

Answer (score 1):

Your photo shows a bulb **inside** a glass envelope. Notice the threads on the outside of the whitish base? That seems to indicate the the envelope unscrews. Once that is off, the bulb itself appears to pull straight out.

Comment: One internet beer...

Comment: The glass envelope is what did not screw out. It just spins around infinitely.

Comment: Maybe try turning it while pulling out? Maybe the threads will engage.

Answer (score 0):

The blurry label behind appears to refer to G4 and G9 bulbs, which should pull straight out.

However, there may be a clear cover separate from the bulb that needs to be removed first.